# unique key for two sides? avoid (1,2) (2,1) also

Tags: mysql

I have a table conversations, I'd like to have only one conversation for each pair of users:

`to` - `from`

if I have user 1 (to) and user 2 (from) I would not like to allow user 2 (to) and user 1 (from) also.

I have unique key:

```
UNIQUE KEY (`to`, `from`),
```

but it only works for one side (1,2) if I have (2,1) it will insert too.

Any ideas how to make this unique key for both sides?

Comment: Potential other solution: You could adjust the process that's inserting your data to always put the lower number into "to". (You can even do that in your SQL statement itself by using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`.)

Comment: @pinkgothic Oh, thank you very much friend!